# Datepicker for dynamically added elements with .on()

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm loading HTML dynamically when a button is clicked. That html is then shown in a modal window. It contains a `<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>` element, for which I'd like to attach a datepicker. I remember jQuery used to support `.live()` for this sort of stuff, but that's been replaced by `on()`.
However, I'm not sure how to correctly use `on()`:

```
$('.datepicker').on('load', function() { $(this).datepicker(); });
```

does not work.

Comment: `.live` and `.on` only work for event handlers. Just call `.datepicker()` after you added the elements to the DOM.

Comment: I'm exactly trying to avoid having to re-call .datepicker() for each added element.

Comment: You *have* to call it one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this also

```
$(function(){
        $(document).on("click", ".datepicker", function(){

            if (!$(this).hasClass("hasDatepicker"))
            {
                $(this).datepicker();
                $(this).datepicker("show");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be called every single time I click somewhere in the document?

Comment: no, as we have passed the specific selector in the on function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use event delegation syntax of .on()

```
(document).on('focusin', '.datepicker', function() { $(this).datepicker(); });
```

Comment: What's `focusin` for?

Comment: @Itay [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusin) is same as focus

Comment: Cool. And you're probably missing a `$` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used javascript code. for datepicker for dynamically created textboxes. I am not able to select date in textbox(2nd row). I am sending my code can u please check and tell me

//here is the javascript for datepicker

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        yearRange: "1980:c",
        maxDate: "+0D",
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true, 
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        //showOn: "button",
        //buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });

               $('.timepicker').timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
               });
});
```

and javacript for addrows dynamically

```
function addRow(tableID) {


        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[2].cells.length;


        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[2].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.innerHTML);
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                case "hidden":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
                case "textarea":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

html for adding rows using table id

```
<td><input id="date" type="text" name="date[]"  class="datepicker" size="10"  value="<?php echo Convert_Date($rows1['date']); ?>"/></td>
```